# Failed to resolve: com.dft.android:onyx-enroll-wizard:4.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio

please help me , i got bellow error.

I am try to integrate `"onyxenrollwizardsampleapp"` Sample app in my Project as a module, but getting below error.

**//Module app:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}


android{

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }


    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


    compileOptions {
    }

}

repositories{
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.diamondfortress.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }

    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.diamondfortress.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
}

    dependencies{
    compile 'com.dft.android:onyx-enroll-wizard:4.1.3'
    }
```

**//project app:

```
build.grade:**

epositories{

    mavenCentral()

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript{

    repositories {

        mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'


    }
}


dependencies{

   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

   compile project(':onyxenrollwizardsampleapp')
}


android{

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
         instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }



}


allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Getting Error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.dft.android:onyx-enroll-wizard:4.1.3
```

Comment: set `compileSdkVersion 22`

Answer (score 1):

At first modify your `build.gradle`

You can use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` instead of `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "" // Set Yours
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

**Finally**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android{

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }


    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


    compileOptions {
    }

}

repositories{
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.diamondfortress.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }

    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.diamondfortress.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
}

    dependencies{
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.dft.android:onyx-enroll-wizard:4.1.3'
    }
```

Then  **`Build menu - Clear Project and Rebuild Project`** .

Comment: Hi IntelliJ Amiya, I added same as above you suggested. Still showing same  Error.........."Error:Failed to resolve: com.dft.android:onyx-enroll-wizard:4.1.3"

Comment: @suresh Have a look here https://github.com/DFTinc/onyx-enroll-wizard-sample-app1

Comment: `dependencies` calling two times in Module app section

Comment: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.dft.android:onyx-enroll-wizard:4.1.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/dft/android/onyx-enroll-wizard/4.1.3/onyx-enroll-wizard-4.1.3.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/dft/android/onyx-enroll-wizard/4.1.3/onyx-enroll-wizard-4.1.3.jar
      * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: yah... I am using github sample app.

Comment: @suresh okay . For testing case set `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` or `apply plugin: 'android'`

Comment: For Testing apply plugin: 'com.android.application' is working for me, but i want to add it as a Module for my project. For this i am using apply plugin: 'android' this, but packages are not importing in my project.

Comment: @suresh This is a very good approach using `Module` . Did you cally like `project(':onyxenrollwizardsampleapp').projectDir = new File('app/modules/onyxenrollwizardsampleapp')` in your `settings.gradle` section